# Is there a way to specify only the latest part of the url in href links?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, single-page-application, svelte, sveltekit

Using [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/), let's say I'm in `players/<PLAYER_ID>/settings/__layout.svelte` and I need two more nested pages:

1. `/profile` in `/players/[PLAYER_ID]/settings/profile.svelte`
2. `/notifications` in `/players/[PLAYER_ID]/settings/notifications.svelte`.

In `__layout.svelte` I have the links:

```html
<a href={`/players/${player.id}/settings/profile`}>Profile</a>

<a href={`/players/${player.id}/settings/notifications`}>Notifications</a>
```

Is there a way to avoid all the links in that `href`?

Something like `/notifications` only?

Comment: Normally, links *without* a leading slash (`/`) are interpreted as relative to your current page. Pages that make use of `/players/[PLAYER_ID]/settings/__layout.svelte` are children of the `/players/[PLAYER_ID]/settings/` directory (or the layout wouldn't be used), so you should be able to access them with `<a href="profile">Profile</a>`, `<a href="notifications">Notifications</a>` etc. This would only work for direct children, however. If you have pages inside subdirectories, then those relative links will point to non-existing `profile` or `notifications` pages within those subdirectories.

Comment: The problem is I have those links in __layout.svelte. The first click is ok, if I click on the second link the url is wrong.